# If a saddle point is on the boundary, is it a local extremum?

Tags: functions, optimization, maxima-minima

Consider the function $f(x)=x^4-4x^3$, which has a saddle point when $x=0$. Now, define the same function on $[0,10]$. How to characterize $x=0$ now? Is it a local extremum (local maximum)? I am confused because $f'(0)=0$ but $f'(0+ \epsilon)<0$.

Comment: Note:  extremum (like minimum and maximum) is singular; extrema (like maxima and minima) is plural

Comment: I suggest you review the definition of the "Saddle Point". The term is usually associated with functions of more than 1 variable. The common term for uni variate functions is "Inflection Point".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you restrict your function as you've said then it's a local maximum, similar to if you restricted it to $[1,10]$, then $x=1$ would be a local maximum.

Comment: Thanks. But what is the justification? As I said, $f'(0)=0$ and the condition I was using for boundary points to be local extrema was to evaluate the first derivative.

Comment: @econ86 If $f'(0)=0$ then it is inconclusive, $f$ could be constant on a (right) neighborhood of $0$ or not. You can use higher derivatives to draw a conclusion.

Comment: But $f''(0)=0$ too, so I am not sure how would I justify it. Does an argument such that $f'(0+\epsilon)<0$ make sense?

Comment: @econ86 You can still answer the question locally by looking at $f'''(0)$ in this case.

Comment: What is the criterion there? How to interpret $f'''(0)<0$ there?

Comment: @econ86 At a left endpoint $a$, if $f'(a)=0,f''(a)=0$ and $f'''(a)<0$ then $a$ endpoint is a local maximum (because moving into the domain from $a$ causes $f$ to decrease).